# Java connection to FileZilla Server

Tags: java, apache-commons-net

This is the thing, I am trying to connect from java to a FileZilla FTPS Server. I can make the login, but when I try to list the files I get an Exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._openDataConnection_(FTPSClient.java:619)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:759)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3293)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3271)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2930)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
```

I have tried every possible solution on line, nothing has worked for me, this is the code I´m using (with apache commons-net):

```
FTPSClient ftps = new FTPSClient();
ftps.setTrustManager(TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager()); 


ftps.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));

int reply;

ftps.connect("xxx.xx.x.xx",8500);
reply = ftps.getReplyCode();

if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
  ftps.disconnect();
  System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
  System.exit(1);
}

if (!ftps.login("user", "*******")) {
  ftps.logout();
}

ftps.setBufferSize(1000);                 
ftps.execPBSZ(0);         
ftps.execPROT("P");
ftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();  
ftps.changeWorkingDirectory("/");
FTPFile[] files = ftps.listFiles();

ftps.logout();
```

I will really appreciate your help guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give me your credentials to filezilla?

Comment: please please please?

Comment: and your credit card

Comment: just joking i am working on your project

Comment: @JackSmith, sorry I can´t :(

Comment: Looks like networkimg problem - wrong port number or proxy in between would be the usual suspects.

Comment: That might be possible, but I can list, download and upload files to the same FTPS server using any ftp client software, so I guess It is not a networking problem :\ ...maybe It is something related to the certificates

Comment: @Jhon Charles A problem about certificates? Could be. Have you installed the remote server's certificate in your current JRE?

Comment: @LittleSanti, yes I have, i already added the ftp .crt to the java cacerts, It did`nt work. Is there a posibillity that I have to send a not self signed certificate to the ftp connection?, i mean, autenticate to the ftp with a real verisign certificate.

Comment: Hum... I don't think the problem is in _authentication_, because you are authenticating with user & pass, not with a certificate... I suppose you can't use active mode instead of passive mode, can you?

Comment: Yes, I already set the active mode, the exception doesn´t happen, but the directory listing doesn´t show any files :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It was something related with the Session reuse, Apache Commons Net has some kind of bug, It does not allow you to reuse the session, I had to implement the cyberduck library [cyberduck source code](https://g.iterate.ch/projects/ITERATE/repos/cyberduck/browse/source/ch/cyberduck/core). I hope this helps someone in the future, thanks for your help.

Comment: I forgot Something, the class we need is FTPClient

Comment: I have a very similar problem. Could you explain more how did you solve it? I tried copying your FTPClient, but did not succeed.